# Concat() VS Union()

Tags: c#, .net

Qual a diferença entre `Concat()` e `Union()` ?

Quando usar `Concat()` e quando usar `Union()` ?

Somente pode ser usado em `list` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O operador `Union()` retorna os elementos de ambas as colecções que sejam distintos.

Assumindo entao que temos duas listas:

```
List<int> primeiraLista = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
List<int> segundaLista = new List<int>{3,4,5,6};
```

Se aplicarmos o operador `Union()`:

```
var unionResultado = primeiraLista.Union(segundaLista);
```

O resultado será uma colecção que contem os elementos da primeira e da segunda lista, *sem os elementos repetidos*:

```
WriteLine("Union: {0}", string.Join(",", unionResultado));  // Union: 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Note que por norma os elementos são comparados por referencia. No entanto este comportamento pode ser alterado nas suas classes fazendo *override* dos métodos `GetHashCode()` e `Equals()`.

Por sua vez o `Concat()` retorna os elementos da primeira lista seguidos dos elementos da segunda lista, *com os elementos repetidos incluidos*.

Assumindo as duas listas anteriores:

```
var concatResultado = primeiraLista.Concat(segundaLista);
WriteLine("Concat: {0}", string.Join(",", concatResultado)); // Concat: 1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6
```

Numa nota final, pode considerar que que `Union()` = `Concat().Distinct()` (embora em termos de implementação e performance sejam diferentes):

```
var concatDistinctResultado = primeiraLista.Concat(segundaLista).Distinct();
WriteLine("Concat Distinct: {0}", string.Join(",", concatDistinctResultado)); // Concat Distinct: 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Ambos os operadores existem no *namespace* `System.Linq` e são aplicáveis a classes que implementem `IEnumerable`.

(Veja os exemplos dados na resposta no [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I1PF1Y).)